# Highcharts Plot two datetime series on top of each other

Tags: plot, highcharts

I'm trying to draw two `datetime` series each with different timestamp ranges on top of each other instead next to teach other. For example if I have two chunks of data, one for last week, another for current week (divided per days) and all I want is to draw them both on top of each other. With the default options both charts are drawn next to each other which does not offer the possibility to compare the value for today (Ex: Tuesday) with the value from Tuesday last week.

Thank you.

Comment: In other words you need to have shared tooltip for two series, but each of them has different ranges (between points), and each point has different timestamp, am I right?

Comment: @SebastianBochan yes.

Comment: So only what comes to my mind is using tooltipformatter and prepare your won algorihtm which will iterate on each point and compare with base.

Comment: please create a fiddle of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would recommend that you not make the xAxis a datetime series. Instead, if your data is recorded daily make the `xAxis.type: 'category'` with the days of the week. Then make your 2 series be one for week1 and the other for week2.

Comment: I thought about it. The problem is that I have 3 filters applied to the same chart:
1. Today vs Yesterday (divided on hours)
2. Current Week vs Last Week (divided on days)
3. Current Month vs Last Month (divided on days)
So I have to calculate `categories` myself after each time a filter is applied. I would prefer to leave this functionality to the Highcharts.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe I have same requirement for my project if you got the answer for your question than please share with me also. I am stuck with this for last two day